# Creating and showing pdf in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, pdf.js

1. I am using [PDFMAKE](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake) to create a base64 encoded pdf and I tried to show it with the Iframe by giving the encoded base64 to iframe src. It works on PC but it didn't work on the mobile ( android and ios ).

   2. So, finally I stumbled upon [Angularjs-PDF](https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf) to show the pdf. Now, I am able see the pdf in mobile. But when I try to give custom width and height respective to device it takes. But the problem arises when I use zoom functionality, the page gets zoomed but it goes out of the screen. I can not even slide or swipe to see the content outside of the screen.

I want to make a pdf on the client side and preview to user with zoom functionality in Ionic.

If anybody got any solution for this please share, Thank You.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So for our company app we used angular-pdf Viewer:

Here is the template for the pdf viewer template, putting inside a ion-scroll allows for pinch zoom and it works great.

```
<div ng-show="notLoaded" class=" center bar bar-subheader">
    <h1 class="title">Loading PDF...</h1>
</div>
<div class="tabs tabs-icon-left">
    <a class="tab-item" ng-click="goPrevious()">
        <i class="icon ion-arrow-left-c"></i>
        Prev
    </a>
    <a class="tab-item" ng-click="goNext()">
        <i class="icon ion-arrow-right-c"></i>
        Next
    </a>
</div>

<ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" class="has-header">
    <canvas class="padding" id="pdf" class="rotate0"></canvas>
</ion-scroll>
```

then on the page that shows the pdf:

```
<ion-view>
    <div class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
        <button ng-click="$ionicGoBack()" class="button button-clear button-light icon-left ion-chevron-left">Go Back</button>
    </div>
    <div class="has-header">
        <ng-pdf template-url="components/pdfviewer/viewer.html" canvasid="pdf" scale="0.675">
        </ng-pdf>
    </div>
</ion-view>
```

You feed the template to the pdf viewer and it will show up on the page.

To use it first include the right js files:

```
<script src="bower_components/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-pdf-viewer/dist/angular-pdf-viewer.min.js"></script>
```

then inject pdf:

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['pdf']);
```

you can read more about it here, but using it in combination with ion-scroll it works just like you think it should on a native device:

https://github.com/winkerVSbecks/angular-pdf-viewer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll test it and get back to you.

Comment: How to give pdf url to this directive. with pdfDelegate or just provide url?

Comment: we just provided it with a url, the pdfDelegate would be useful if you wanted to have more than one pdf on the same page so you could identify which one is which

Comment: you're actually using https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf not winkerVSbecks as you've linked

Comment: Since you haven't mentioned it, you have to set the attribute `overflow-scroll` to `false` in the `ion-scroll` tag, otherwise it might cause some problem.

Comment: @JessPatton   hi, i have the requirement to show the pdf without download option for the user. i search over the internet . but not able to fount the solution. my post link is here. can you please help me out..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496455/how-to-show-pdf-file-in-ionic-app-with-out-download    i tried more than 1 week. but not able to get. i am using ionic 1

Comment: @JessPatton hi, i have the requirement to show the pdf without download option for the user. i search over the internet . but not able to fount the solution. my post link is here. can you please help me out..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496455/how-to-show-pdf-file-in-ionic-app-with-out-download    i tried more than 1 week. but not able to get. i am using ionic 1

Comment: @JessPatton Do you know of any option to load the full pdf ( multiple pages ). Currently to my knowledge angular-pdf only allows one page to be visible and you have to press a button to navigate between pages. Any way we can load all the pages and show them by scrolling vertically. Thanks in advance.