# How to open pdf file into a div or a tab using ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

> How to open pdf file into a div or a tab using ionic 3 ? Using below
>   code I can open pdf by pdf reader outside from app. I want to show it into a div. Please give me some suggestion.

```
import { DocumentViewer } from '@ionic-native/document-viewer';


constructor(private document: DocumentViewer) { }

...
const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
  title: 'My PDF'
}

this.document.viewDocument('assets/myFile.pdf', 'application/pdf', options)
```

Comment: That is native component build in android and ios code so you cannot open in div

Comment: take a look to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434553/creating-and-showing-pdf-in-ionic) it might solve your problem

Comment: This is ionic1 or angular 1 so i need into ionic 3 or 2

Comment: sorry, rectification, this *might have helped* solve your problem. On the tool's github repo they talk about adapting it for angular 2, someone apparently done it 75%.. i have no other clue for the moment

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pdf viewer component for Angular 2+ application.
You can write your own or use some available at npm.
Example: https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer

Template:

```
<ion-content>
 <pdf-viewer
  [src]="pdfSrc" 
  [render-text]="true"
  style="display: block;"
 ></pdf-viewer>
</ion-content>
```

component.ts

```
pdfSrc: string = '/pdf-test.pdf';
```

Comment: Did u try it ? Pdf file is not scrolling