# How to browse PDF files from mobile file system with IONIC version 1 in android and IOS devices by using cordova plugins

Tags: file, pdf, ionic-framework, file-upload, cordova-plugins

I am using IONIC version 1 with cordova. I have tried many cordova plugins to browse the PDF files from mobile file system.

But None of them has worked for me.

Comment: This link can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434553/creating-and-showing-pdf-in-ionic

Comment: Thanks Sam. But my requirement is Browse the PDF files from mobile file system and then upload from both android and IOS devices.

Comment: Did you try the file opener plugin from Cordova ?

Comment: Yes I have used file opener plugin of Cordova & it use to read any file if we provide the file path. There is no issue with file opening and uploading. I have already used Cordova camera plugin to browse the images from mobile file system and it is working fine. Now my requirement is to browse & upload PDF file from mobile. Still I have the working code to upload PDF file but didn't find any plug-in to browse the PDF files.